# Is there any Python implementation of set() with key argument?

Tags: python, set

#### Question

I would like to know if there are any python functions that implement `set()` with a `key` argument, analogous to e.g. the `key` in `sorted(iterable, *, key=None, reverse=False)`?

I think this feature would be useful for certain cases, especially when comparing custom objects without having to change its `hash()` function.

#### Desired effect

Example 1

```
iterable = [1.0, 1.5, 2.0, 2.5]
x = set(iterable)                 # yields {1.0, 1.5, 2.0, 2.5}
y = set(iterable, key=math.floor) # yields {1.0, 2.0}
```

Example 2

```
iterable = ['abc', 'ade', 'bbc', 'abc', 'bfg']
x = set(iterable)                     # yields {'abc', 'ade', 'bbc', 'bfg'}
y = set(iterable, key=lambda x: x[0]) # yields {'abc', 'bbc'}
```

#### Which to choose

I could imagine that this would not be implemented due to the difficulty of choosing which object is selected if a duplicate is found. However, this could be overcome by some strategy, e.g. 'choose first', 'choose random', 'choose last'.

#### Answer

Thank you for all of your responses, the most elegant solution for this problem was suggested by [Daniel Roseman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/104349/daniel-roseman):

```
key = math.floor # Or any desired key function
y   = set({key(i): i for i in iterable}.values())
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Isn't that basically a dictionary, where the key is the result of applying the function to the value?

```
y = {math.floor(i): i for i in iterable}
```

Comment: Yes indeed, I hadn't thought of that, it would indeed be a dictionary except that it would discard the dictionary key. In that case `y = {math.floor(i): i for i in iterable}.values()` would suffice. Thanks!

Comment: FYI: Last value is selected in such implementation

Answer (score 4):

You would implement that the other way around, with a custom type:

```
class FlooredFloat:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(math.floor(self.value))

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return other.value == self.value


iterable = [1.0, 1.5, 2.0, 2.5]
x = set(map(FlooredFloat, iterable))
```

Comment: A wrapper class providing the `hash` function... neat. Then loopup elements as `FlooredFloat(someotherfloat) in x`. But shouldn't that also implement `__eq__`?

Comment: Presumably you'd then unwrap the set again to continue working with it, `map(attrgetter('value'), x)`. And yes, forgot `__eq__`, thanks.

Comment: Hm, but if you just revert to the values, you can't use fast lookup using the hash.

Comment: Depends on what you want to use it for. Just deduplication, or more set-like work.

Answer (score 2):

[Daniel Roseman's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/104349/daniel-roseman) [observation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51635247/298607) of using a dict is brilliant.

If syntactically you wanted something that looked like a key function, it is easy enough to write:

```
def key(it, func):
    seen=set()
    for e in it:
        x=func(e)
        if x not in seen:
            seen.add(x)
            yield True
        else:
            yield False
```

Then you can use a set comprehension with that (and `zip`):

```
>>> iterable = [1.0, 1.5, 2.0, 2.5]
>>> {x for x,y in zip(iterable, key(iterable, math.floor)) if y}
{1.0, 2.0}
>>> {x for x,y in zip(iterable, key(iterable, lambda s: s[0])) if y}
{'abc', 'bbc'}
```

You could also write a function this way:

```
def set_with_key(it, func):
    seen=set()
    return {e for e in iterable if func(e) not in seen and not seen.add(func(e))}

>>> set_with_key([1.0, 1.5, 2.0, 2.5], math.floor)
{1.0, 2.0}
>>> set_with_key(['abc', 'ade', 'bbc', 'abc', 'bfg'], lambda s: s[0])
{'abc', 'bbc'}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make it a function:

```
import itertools
import math


def strategy(items):
    return items[0]


def set_with_key(iterable, key):
    iterable = sorted(iterable, key=key)
    groups = [list(x[1]) for x in itertools.groupby(iterable, key)]
    return [strategy(items) for items in groups]


iterable = [1.0, 1.5, 2.0, 2.5]
print(set_with_key(iterable, math.floor))

iterable = ["abc", "ade", "bbc", "abc", "bfg"]
print(set_with_key(iterable, lambda x: x[0]))
```